# Iterating over SWbemPropertySet objects

Tags: com, wmi

A WQL query in WMI using the COM API returns a SWbemObjectSet. From this, we can use the [ItemIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to iterate over all objects in the set, resulting in many [SWbemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s. These have a `Properties_` property, which returns a [SWbemPropertySet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This object has a `Count` property, but no `ItemIndex` method, instead only an `Item` method, which takes a string name of the property to fetch. I'd like to iterate over all available properties, thus I don't have the name available. I've tried calling an `ItemIndex` method, but (as per the documentation) it does not exist on this object. There are many VBScript documents around that do something like `For Each prop in object.Properties_`, so I assume this is somehow possible.

How can I find all properties?

Comment: Which language are you using to access the WMI?

Comment: I'm using [Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365286/query-wmi-from-go).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the `ItemIndex` property only exist in some versions of the  `Microsoft WMI Scripting Library` you can find more info about this topic on this article which I wrote some time ago 
[`Be careful when you import the Microsoft WMI Scripting Library`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/be-careful-when-you-import-the-microsoft-wmiscripting-library/) (The code uses Delphi but the same applies to any language using this Library).

Now to iterate over the elements of an [`SWbemPropertySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you must get a instance to the enumerator accessing the `_NewEnum` property which provides a method for enumerating a collection of variants using the [`IEnumVARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. This is done *automagically* by vbscript, but in others languages like Delphi or C++ must be done manually.

Try this Delphi sample

```pascal
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants,
  WbemScripting_TLB in 'WbemScripting_TLB.pas';

procedure ShowProperties(const WMINameSpace, WMIClass : string);
var
  WMIServices     : ISWbemServices;
  SWbemObjectSet  : ISWbemObjectSet;
  SObject         : ISWbemObject;
  LProperty       : ISWbemProperty;
  Enum, Enum2     : IEnumVariant;
  TempObj, TempObj2: OleVariant;
  Value           : Cardinal;
  SWbemPropertySet: ISWbemPropertySet;
begin
  WMIServices := CoSWbemLocator.Create.ConnectServer('.', WMINameSpace,'', '', '', '', 0, nil);
  SWbemObjectSet := WMIServices.ExecQuery(Format('Select * FROM %s',[WMIClass]), 'WQL', 0, nil);
  Enum := (SWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if (Enum.Next(1, TempObj, Value) = S_OK) then
  begin
    SObject     := IUnknown(TempObj) as ISWBemObject;
    SWbemPropertySet := SObject.Properties_;
    Enum2 := (SWbemPropertySet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while (Enum2.Next(1, TempObj2, Value) = S_OK) do
    begin
      LProperty     := IUnknown(TempObj2) as ISWbemProperty;
      Writeln(LProperty.Name);
      TempObj2:=Unassigned;
    end;
    TempObj:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ShowProperties('root\cimv2','Win32_BaseBoard');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

I hope which you can translate this sample to the Go language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the object class to get all the properties.  Here's an example where the object class properties are used to convert a WMI query to a stringified JSON object.

```vb
function getWMIObjectJSON(strNameSpace,strClass,strFilter)
    strComputer = "." 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
            strComputer & "\" & strNameSpace)
    Set objClass = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
            strComputer & "\" & strNameSpace & ":" & strClass)      
    colCount=0
    rtn="{""description"":""" & escStr(strNameSpace & ":" & strClass & " " & strFilter) & """,""title"":""" & _
            escStr(strNameSpace & ":" & strClass) & """,""columns"":["  
    For Each objClassProperty In objClass.Properties_       
        if colCount>0 then rtn=rtn & ","
        rtn=rtn & """" & escStr(objClassProperty.Name) & """"
        colCount=colCount + 1
    Next    
    Set colData = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from " & strClass & " " & strFilter)        
    rtn=rtn & "],""record_count"":" & colData.Count & ",""records"":["
    rowCount=0
    For Each objData In colData
        if rowCount > 0 then rtn=rtn & ","
        rtn=rtn & "{"
        colCount=0
        For Each objClassProperty In objClass.Properties_ 
            if colCount > 0 then rtn=rtn & ","
            rtn=rtn & """" & escStr(objClassProperty.Name) & """:""" & _
                    escStr(objData.Properties_(objClassProperty.Name).Value) & """"
            colCount=colCount + 1
        Next
        rtn=rtn & "}"
        rowCount=rowCount + 1
    Next    
    rtn=rtn & "]}"
    getWMIObjectJSON = rtn
end function

desktop = getWMIObjectJSON("root\cimv2","Win32_Desktop","where Name like '%u%'")
WScript.Echo desktop
```

```xml
<package>
<job id="wmiExample">
   <script language="VBScript" src="wmi.vbs"/>     
   <script language="JScript">     
      var desktop = eval("(" + getWMIObjectJSON("root\cimv2","Win32_Desktop","") + ")");
      for(d in desktop.records){
        WScript.Echo(desktop.records[d].Name);
      }
   </script>
</job>
</package>
```