# How to tell if a folder is shared with GoLang or CMD?

Tags: windows, go, cmd

Is there a way to tell if a folder is shared For example I have folder D:/data1 I would like to know if it is shared or if is not.
 Is this possible to do with golang or CMD commands? Is there a example on how to do this?
My goal is to be able to pass in a root folder D:/data2 and tell if is a shared folder. 
Example of what i would like to do.

```
if shared("D:/data2") {
 //handle if it is shared
} else {
 //handle not shared folder
}
```

I just have not bin able to find a way to detect if the folder is shared.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm far from a windows cli expert.

You're on the right path in terms of os/exec.Cmd to execute OS specific commands on your target system.

You should be able to use the `net share` [command](http://www.computerhope.com/nethlp.htm) to display all current local shares. Unfortunately while you can check a sharename with that command too, there doesn't appear to be any reverse lookup, so you'll probably have to write some code that can poke through the results of `net share` and look for the relevant path.

The output is formatted nicely enough, so it shouldn't be that difficult to write a function that uses `net share` to create a map of all windows shares for easy look up.

Answer (score -1):

The [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net) solution to this problem is to use WMI. Since this is very Windows-specific, I don't believe anything out of the Go standard library will help you here.

We can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365286/query-wmi-from-go) that a third-party package does exist for using WMI, as well as [another package](https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi/blob/master/wmi.go) from Stack Exchange. You can try to make something out of the combination of the C# solution and the API available with those WMI packages.